# What are society's assumptions about the essential goodness of people?

Tags: ethics, human-nature, philosophy-of-social-sciences, axiology, anthropology

What are society's assumptions about the essential goodness of people? Does society assume that people are essentially good, bad, or both?

Comment: This is a question for a political science, psychology, or sociology site. It's not philosophy.

Comment: The Book "[Liars and Outliers](https://www.amazon.com/Liars-Outliers-Enabling-Society-Thrive/dp/1118143302)" by Bruce Schneier may be a useful pragmatic answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

What is [human nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_nature) depends on the society and individuals in society. This is the idea behind [cultural relativism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_relativism). From WP:

> Cultural relativism is the position that there is no universal standard to measure cultures by, and that all cultural values and beliefs must be understood relative to their cultural context, and not judged based on outside norms and values. Proponents of cultural relativism also tend to argue that the norms and values of one culture should not be evaluated using the norms and values of another.

For instance, Judeo-Christian societies, according to the Abrahamic tradition, people are inherently sinful. Today, this is known in theological circles as [original sin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_sin). From WP:

> Original sin is the Christian doctrine that holds that humans, through the fact of birth, inherit a tainted nature with a proclivity to sinful conduct in need of regeneration.

Thus, there is a presumption people are born bad. In Christian thinking, if you prostrate yourself before God, ask for forgiveness for being bad, and embrace the teaching and divinity of Jesus of Nazareth, you will receive [God's divine grace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_grace).

For an atheist, obviously such pronouncements are supernatural and not meaningful. Atheists reject beliefs that come from divine revelation, and may take a scientific approach to human nature. One recent cognitive scientist's take on human nature is Steven Pinker in his book [The Blank Slate: The Modern Denial of Human Nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blank_Slate) in which he attacks the belief that there is no human nature. In this view, it's best to see that Pinker does not believe that people are good or bad, but both and very complex. Modern secular thinking tends to presume people behave well until they have a good reason to behave poorly.

The best place to come to your own conclusions might be starting with the SEP's article [*Human Nature*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/human-nature/). From the article:

> Talk of human nature is a common feature of moral and political discourse among people on the street and among philosophers, political scientists and sociologists. This is largely due to the widespread assumption that true descriptive or explanatory claims making use of the concept of human nature have, or would have, considerable normative significance.

Good? Bad? Confused? People are very complex in every culture, and it might best not to [oversimply](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oversimplification) or rely on the views of anyone society. I haven't read it, but I did find [Culture and Human Nature (GB)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Culture_and_Human_Nature/fdHTDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) which may go into the concepts surrounding your question.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single 'society', so it doesn't make sense to ask whether society's assumptions are one thing or another, since the assumptions vary by society and even within a society. Also, you need to distinguish between explicit and implicit assumptions, since I suspect you will rarely find a document that begins 'This society assumes that...'.

Society in the UK, which is the only one I know well, seems to have mixed assumptions on whether people are good or bad. For example, there are quite robust 'safeguarding' arrangements for the protection of children and other vulnerable people, which include mandatory criminal record checks for people who work with vulnerable groups. Likewise there are regulatory bodies established specifically to guard against malpractice in many professions. All of that- and a wide range of other regulations and laws besides- suggests a presumption that some people are not inherently good. On the other hand, there are many regulations that are not enforced in practice, and many aspects of life that are not regulated at all, which suggests that society is content to assume either that people will act with good intentions or that the possible harm is too small to warrant arrangements to combat it.

Comment: UK society is the only society you know? You don't have a family? Or a religious organization? Or an educational community? Or an employer? That seems a little bit of a stretch. Nation states aren't the only type of societies.

Comment: @JD good point, thanks, but I was specifically limiting my answer to society at the national level.

Comment: +1 Well that's reasonable of you.  : )

Comment: @JD much appreciated!